# Updating multiple JFrame elements faster while looping through 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, optimization, multidimensional-array

I'm creating a version of Conway's game of life and it's working fine, however when the the 2D array gets larger you can see the game updating line by line (as it is looping through the array).

The method below is what I'm using to update the game. cellList is the array containing each cell's state. 1 = alive, 0 = dead. The method is drawing a rectangle for each cell in the array.

Is there a way to loop through the array faster? This is the first time I've really used swing for a project so I'm not familiar with what else I could use.

Thanks!

```
public void paintCells()
{
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    for(int x=0;x<cellList.length;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<cellList.length;y++)
        {
            int rectX = winX/width * y;
            int rectY = winY/height * x;
            int rectWidth = winX/width;
            int rectHeight = winY/height;
            if(cellList[x][y] == 1)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillRect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            }
            else
            {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.fillRect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

#### Solved

Viewing the program on a monitor connected by HDMI updated arrays as big as 700x700 smoothly. I think the main cause of the problem was the fact that I was using an older monitor connected by VGA.

Comment: Take a look at the code in my article [John Conway’s Game of Life in Java Swing](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=504). I've not encountered a painting speed problem like you describe.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I'll check that out. The problem is only noticeable when the array is larger than ~100x100. Thanks!

Comment: If your code only works well with an HDMI monitor, then you probably have a problem. Are you doing something funny like forcing it to synchronize or telling it to paint immediately all the time or turning off double buffering? You should make sure double buffering is enabled, force synchronization at most once per screen paint, and only do immediate painting if you *really* know what you're doing.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm telling it to paint immediately all the time I guess, the above method is being called pretty much continuously if that's what you mean. I haven't disabled double buffering (it's on by default in swing isn't it?)

Comment: The method to avoid is `paintImmediately`. If you're not using it, then it's not the problem.

Comment: @dfeuer Ah ok, I'm not using paintImmediately. I'll play around with it again in the morning and see what I can change. Thanks!